# unable to parse json response from google

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I am trying to parse Json response from [This URL](http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=Delhi&daddr=Mumbai%20to%3ahyderabad). I have used SBJsonParser, MTJSON and another parser but i am getting NULL in all three case.

```
apiUrlStr = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=Delhi&daddr=Mumbai+to:hyderabad";
NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];
NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

SBJsonParser *json = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [json objectWithString:apiResponse];
NSLog(@"dictionary=%@", [json objectWithString:apiResponse]);
```

> 2011-12-09 16:59:01.226 MapWithRoutes[2523:207] dictionary=(null)

Plz suggest me something

Comment: Your post is missing al lot of essential parts: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @rckoenes, I don't think it is missing anything. JSON fails to decode anyway.

Comment: Thats what i am saying. What am i suppose to do now??

Comment: @rckoenes the man has tried almost everything. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oke if checked the url you gave with [JSONlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) and the JSON is not valid. thus can not be parsed by any library.

If you used [JSONkit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) you can supply a `NSError` object with the parse call to see what went wrong:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [apiResponse objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone error:&error]; 

if (!dictionary) {
   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Parse error on line 1:
{    tooltipHtml: " (2,13
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'

Comment: Ah, the keys in a JSON object like tooltipHtml are missing string quotes.

Comment: Yep, not legit JSON since the object keys are not quoted.