# how to extract value of an element from JSON data using RegEx

Tags: iphone, ios, regex

I am trying to extract value of "points" element from JSON data using

```
    NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];
```

but there are more than one "points" elements in the JSON data. Plz help me i dont know much about regular expressions.
i am getting JSON Data from [this link](http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=Delhi&daddr=Mumbai%20to%3ahyderabad)

Comment: i am not sure if you can use mapkit to display directions , as it is against the legal clause of google. please confirm it from someone.

Comment: But thats what we are doing using there Directions api. right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a JSON scanner.

Ensure that you have the JSON in an `NSString`, not an `NSData`.

Here is a method that uses an `NSScanner` instead of a regular expression:

```
NSMutableArray *pointList = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *pointsString;
BOOL success = YES;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:encodedPoints];

while (YES) {
    success = [scanner scanUpToString:@"points:\"" intoString:nil];
    success = [scanner scanString:@"points:\"" intoString:nil];
    if (success == NO)
        break;
    success = [scanner scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:&pointsString];
    [pointList addObject:pointsString];
}

// Show results by print lengths of the found points
for (NSString *point in pointList)
    NSLog(@"point length: %i", point.length);
```

NSLog output:

```
point length: 22058
point length: 8889
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JSON parser for this as that would be more correct/idea for dealing with JSON than using a regex which is prone to failure.

Comment: JSON parsers are not working because it is giving invalid JSON response

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444697/unable-to-parse-json-response-from-google

Comment: It depends on which JSON parser you are using and where it fails. To my old eyes, the JSON looked good.

Comment: I saw the other thread. It seems that they are not generating JSON to consume as JSON but instead for setting some variables in Javascript. You could just use the following to make it proper JSON.

Comment: Can you please check it once?? i dont want any code just confirm it if it is parseable or not.

Comment: It is not parsable without modifications.

Comment: can you tell me how to modify it ??

Comment: jsonlint.com let me knew what was wrong. A couple of regexs would fix it. The first problem is with keys in a JSON object. It can be fixed by \(\w\+\)\(\:\)/"\1"\2/cg regular expression. The second problem is first value which is not escaping certain characters. Apart from that, JSON is correct.